# How to read HDD from an IBM PS/1 model 2133

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ide, ps1

I have an IDE HDD removed from an IBM PS/1 2133.

So far I've tried plugging into an IDE-USB adapter on Windows and Linux, both show a "no media" error, although a device does show up.

How can I get the data off?

Comment: Stretching my memory, old drives had a jumper setting on them to say whether they were master or slave.  Maybe you need to change this jumper ?

Comment: This^^^ Some adapters required "master" and others "cable select". You need to test it.

Comment: OP here, I was using a USB-IDE adapter that was apparently causing my problem. Switching to a machine with a real IDE port solved the problem.